# UILabel text is not displaying properly

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uilabel

I want to show the text in uilabel. The text is `,000124520.061112782.,3299985343,` 
 I have assign line break mode to character wrap and number of lines to 0. But in label first line is displayed only the , and then other characters are displayed in next line. But i want to display the text in two lines only. But it is displayed in three lines. I don't know why , is displayed in first line. Please anyone help me.

Comment: if that UILabel width is short then text then that moved to second line only.

Comment: yes i know that if width is shorten then the last characters are moved to next line right

Comment: all the characters except , moved to next line i don't know why

Comment: if fond size not meter then you have to set font smaller and set full width of UIlabel of uiview width.

Comment: it is happens only when the , as the first character

Answer (score 0):

You should set the numberOfLines of your UILabel to 1.

Answer (score 0):

When the `numberOfLines` property of a UILabel is set to 0 the UILabel will render its text over as many lines as it needs - e.g. its infinite.  To fix your text to a single line you should therefore set the property to 1.

Obviously your text may not all fit on a single line so you should also set the UILabel's `minimumScaleFactor` property to allow the UILabel to adjust its font size downward (to the supplied limit) to fit the content into the frame of the label.  You will also need to set the UILabel's `adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth` property to YES.

Further to the above an easy way to calculate the value for the minimumScaleFactor property is to divide the minimum font size by the maximum font size.  So, say for example your label's default font size was 12 and you were happy for it to drop to 10, then assign the minimum scale factor as follows:

```
myLabel.minimumScaleFactor = 10/12.0f;
```